# SQL : Count , Sum and Group by

Tags: sql, count, group-by, sum

I'm querying database :

```
ID    Date1       Date2        Status  FK
1    12-05-2016  20-05-2016    ok       3
2    24-05-2016  27-05-2016    NOK      3
3    29-05-2016  06-06-2016    OK       4
```

I need to get the sum grouping by month of date(date1 or date2) and fk.

Something like this :

```
Month        Sum        FK
5            2          3
5            1          4
6            1          4
```

I tried this, but it not giving me what I expected

---

```
select Month(date1)as date1 ,MONTH(date2) as date2 ,COUNT(*) as sum, fk
from table
where status ='OK'
group by fk , MONTH(date1), MONTH(date2);
```

---

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I am not yet able to understand your question properly: Your SQL statement looks ok to me, but does not fit to the second table above (in the second table there is only one column for month) - moreover, what do you mean with "date1 or date2"? when should be used the one or the other?

Comment: because month of date1 could not to be the same of date2 ; so in this case, i have to count  the sum for each month , even if it refers to the same record. hoping that my question is  more clear :)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
select sum(sm),fk,dt from 
(
select Month(date1)as dt ,COUNT(*) as sm, fk

from table

where status ='OK'

group by fk , MONTH(date1)

union all
select Month(date2)as dt ,COUNT(*) as sm, fk

from table

where status ='OK'

group by fk , MONTH(date2)

)
group by dt,fk
```

Comment: Better change to `UNION ALL`, there might be duplicates which will be removed by `UNION`.

Comment: Thank you Saeid and dnoeth ;  but i'm using sql server and select (select ) gives me a syntax Error ...

Comment: of course : Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: sorry I had forgot to add "from" to the very first select now check again

Comment: yes i already did it , but i got this error : 
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.

Comment: let me fix it. Unfortunately I do not have any database installed

Comment: what if you remove the sum from the first select and group by at the end. just for test to see if it returns any result or not. let me know

Comment: that's exactly what  i'm trying to do but .. :  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @Magnolia You are welcome. Please consider my answer as accepted answer if it helped